# How can I format output values?

Tags: java, format

[image]

This my output file. I'used standart "System.out.print()" for writing operation. There is a tab space between each value. But due to difference of word size, format looks bad. How can I fix the format of output?

Comment: How do you store data in memory?

Comment: Why don't you enclose your data in a table?

Comment: This photo is from Eclipse console. I can't use a table in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should print an element of your String by column every two tabs. If you need more tabs because the names are too long, you can increase the number of tabs in `//here` rememberingh that every tab have a length of 8 characters.

```
     try{
          FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt", true);
          PrintStream out = new PrintStream(file);

                        String s=line;
                        String[] items = s.split("\t");

                            for(String item : items){
                                if(item.length()<8){            //here
                                    out.print(item + "\t\t" );  //here
                                }else{
                                    if(item.length()>16){       //here
                                    out.print(item + "\t" );
                                    }
                                }

              }catch (IOException e){
                  System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                  System.exit(1);
              }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a .csv file which can be opened in Excel and will give you data divided by column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.format`, you can specify `width` to make things consistent.

Check out the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) explanation.